# What is my native language?

Tags: language-acquisition

I was adopted from China when I was 10 months old. I have lived in the US since then and English is the only language I am fluent in. Would my native language and first language be English? What is my mother language?

Also, if possible, I would like a simple explanation of first language, native language, and mother tongue?

Thanks!

Comment: @Review For those who are voting to reopen the question, could you point out in what you think this question is different from the one that was marked as a duplicate?